# How to allow web.config files as normal files and allow download IIS inside a virtual directory

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am working on a Unity 3D game which upon build for Windows generates game.exe and game_Data file and folder. The Game_Data folder contains a directory called **Game_Data\Mono\etc\mono\2.0**.

The directory files are shown in image.

[image: Mono 2.o Dir structure]

The **Browsers** directory contains one file called **Compact.browser.**

The Current Scenario.
1. These game files are hosted on a server where IIS 7.5 is running.
The game resource files are served in virtual directory of the game website.

2. I've made few changes to the website's root web.config file so that all filetypes are allowed to download only in the game resources folder on server.
3. Yes, all file types including .html, .aspx, .xml, .config, .browser, .map etc are all downloading as normal files.

**The problem**

1. As you see the directory structure there is a web.config file inside the game resources folder. The file has nothing to do with website configuration but with the game (which is on client side after downloading).
2. As  the files are served as individual files each file is downloaded separately. So when the client tries to download all files including the contents of the above folder.
3. Due to this web.config file, contents of the directory is not downloading. If I delete this web.config file all of the .aspx, .config, .map files are downloading. Also there are some other folders where many different files are downloading properly.
4. But this web.config file is also required for the game, and **it is not allowing it be downloaded with other files too in the directory shown above**.

I've tried to look into the solution. Found some hints to avoid inheritance in nested config files. But actually I want to completely treat this file as a normal file, not as a site configuration file.

I think you got my problem. Please let me know your suggestions. You can say adding Mime types. But actuall all of the file types are downloading including .config files. Except the file named web.config.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same problem, and I think I found the solution: there is a way to tell IIS not to interpret web.config files.

To do this, modify the `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` file (I haven't found a way to do this in the IIS user interface), by specifying `allowSubDirConfig="false"` for the relevant `<virtualDirectory>` element:

```
<configuration>
  <system.applicationHost>
    <!-- ... -->
    <sites>
      <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
        <application path="/">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
          <virtualDirectory path="/Staging" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Staging" allowSubDirConfig="false" />
        </application>
    <bindings> <!-- ... --> </bindings>
  </site>
```

See http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory for the details.

The problem is, it still won't let you download the web.config file, it keeps returning a 404 - Not found, even after removing all handlers.

**Edit** - found the solution. The short answer is that in your web.config, you should clear the `fileExtensions` and `hiddenSegments` lists:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <hiddenSegments>
        <clear />
      </hiddenSegments>
      <fileExtensions>
        <clear />
      </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

I've written a [blog article about it](http://blogs.infosupport.com/getting-iis-to-serve-any-file-type/) that explains all the details.

Comment: No, to What I did is, I renamed all files that start with web.config with web2.config (or whatever) and after downloading a file, I'll rename it back to web.config.

But this is not a solution. This is just a workaround.

Comment: @KumarChikkanna I found the solution, see my updated answer and my blog post.

Comment: @KumarChikkanna If this is the solution, could you place the checkmark? This way, others can see that there's an answer to this problem.